# input types on server side controls

Tags: asp.net, iphone, ipad, server-side

I'm using asp.net to build an ipad webapp. I know that using `input type="email"` will cause the keyboard layout on the ipad to change to handle email input more easily than the default.  The problem is I'm using a server side text box control.  Does anyone know how to make a server side control do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
textBox.Attributes.Add("type", "email")
```

or write it out like this in your aspx

```
<input type="email" id="emailTextBox" name="emailTextBox" runat="server" />
```

Comment: I found this person posted about creating his own custom server controls to get the html5 functionality: http://www.html5asp.com/Demo.aspx

Comment: Looks like you can then create controls like this: `<html5:EmailLink runat="server" ID="lnkEmail" Subject="Love your software" Body="Sample Body Text" 
MailTo="JoeCool@YourDomain.com" CC="JaneDoe@HerDomain.com" Text="Send Email" />`