# Can I use Angular's email validation on an ASP.net WebForms Text Input

Tags: angularjs, webforms

I am trying to use Angular validation on an email field, which is a ASP.NET Webforms server side input box.  I am using the html below:

```
<input type="email" runat="server" id="txtNoCanDo" ng-model="data.email"/>
```

I get the following error from asp.net: **Error 79  'email' is not a valid type for an input tag.**

I presume Webforms needs to understand the type value to instantiate the correct server-side control type, and raises an error when parsing this since it does know about the email type.

Is there any way to work around this, possibly by adding the validation requirement for angular in a different way?

Comment: ASP.Net 4.0 HtmlGenericControl does not support the "Type" attribute as defined in your code http://stackoverflow.com/a/9801984/2326610. I think .net >= 4.5 has support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the aspx file, change the type to text, i.e.

```
<input type="text" runat="server" id="txtNoCanDo" ng-model="data.email"/>
```

Between your script tags for JQuery and Angular, add the following javascript:

```
$(function() {
    var emailbox = $("#txtNoCanDo");
    emailbox.replaceWith(emailBox.clone().attr('type', 'email'));
});
```