# Numeric updown TextBox not displaying buttons in IE

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, numericupdown

I have an HTML `input` control

```
<input id="textBox1" class="form-control" runat="server"/>
```

I add the following C# code to make it a Numeric updown control:

```
textBox1.Attributes["type"] = "number";
textBox1.Attributes["min"] = "0";
textBox1.Attributes["max"] = "50";
textBox1.Attributes["step"] = "1";
```

This is working fine in Chrome but in Internet Explorer the updown buttons are not displaying.

What should I do to display the buttons in IE also?

I know that a similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955731/input-type-number-not-working-in-ie10) but I thought adding the Attributes in code behind could overcome this as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801120/html5-email-input-cannot-assign-id-and-runat-server-asp-net-4) in Sachin Gupta's answer.

Answer (score 1):

See https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number 
Comment attached to IE versions is:

> UI widget does not include increment/decrement buttons.